# Showing progress of raster geoprocessing tools with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, geoprocessing, progress

**Background**: I am doing DEM resampling for a pretty big raster (341020x341020 cells, ~ 10 GB file size, ~ 433 GB uncompressed size) with arcpy. My Python script (uses 64-bit Geoprocessing) has been running for more than half a day with the output file size is ~ 20 GB so far and I have no idea how long I will have to wait for it to finish.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/GIS"

inRaster = 'dem_2m.tif'
resampleRaster = 'dem_1m.tif'
newCellSize = '1'
resamplingMethod = 'BILINEAR'

arcpy.Resample_management(in_raster=inRaster, out_raster=resampleRaster, 
                          cell_size=newCellSize, resampling_type=resamplingMethod)
```

**Question**: Is there a way to show the percentage of completion when the script is running? Something similar to this when we use ArcToolbox within ArcGIS interface

[image]

[image]

**System info**: Windows 10 Enterprise, ArcGIS 10.6.1 with 64-bit Geoprocessing tools, Core i7-8850H (12 cores), 32 GB RAM, 300 GB free SSD disk space